# building a plugin using Piwik (integrating json with piwik)

Tags: php, json, matomo

I want to build a plugin for piwik which can plot graphs by reading a json file. I want to bypass the whole process of having to acess a mysql database, is there an easy way that I could achieve this. Also I want to build a UI with standard things such as checkboxes, textfields etc, can I do that using piwik

Answer (score 2):

This is a very vague question.  [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) seems to be a locally-installed web analytics program written in PHP.

You haven't told us what your plugin would do.  How would it do whatever it needs to do without touching the database?

Have you read [their plugin documentation](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/Plugins/HowToWritePluginIntroduction)?  It's conveniently titled "How To Write a Plugin", btw.  Hard to miss.  It looks like the plugin is responsible for creating it's own HTML, so that at least answers your question about building a UI.

Comment: The link is dead, they changed the name to matomo the first url redirects to https://matomo.org/ the old docs can be found in wayback machine from 2016 https://web.archive.org/web/20150924182704/http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/Plugins/HowToWritePluginIntroduction just in case someone need to this in old Piwik.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at the developer friendly example plugin called ExampleUI, which shows how to plot line graphs, pie charts, tag clouds, and report 'tables' with automatic links to the API export, etc.

Enable ExampleUI in your Piwik installation, and click on the ExampleUI tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? let me know